# Capturing full screen shot of webpage content using selenium 3 webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver

i am trying to take a full content screen shot of web page . but i am only getting view based screen shot with following code. browser is firefox i am using SELENIUM 3 web driver.

```
File scrFile5 = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            try {

                FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile5, new File("C:\\test.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

how i can achieve the same.

Comment: We are only able to take screenshot for the visible part of the webpage but we  don't have any option to take screen shot for entire webpage by srolling down/up and can't even by PrintScreen/SysRq

Comment: thanks for your reply , but incase of selenium ide for fire fox i am manage to take screen shot of entire content . but not able to do it via java code

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make use of **RemoteWebDriver** interface. Are you working with Firefox or IE?  See below

```
File screenshotFile = null;
            try {
                // This checks to make sure we're not running an
                // incompatible driver to take a screenshot (e.g.
                // screenshots are not supported by the HtmlUnitDriver)

                //the following line will throw a ClassCastException if the current driver is not a browser typed driver
                RemoteWebDriver compatibleDriver = (RemoteWebDriver) driver;

                screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot) compatibleDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                //this driver does not support screenshots.
                // this should get logged as a warning -- this only means the driver cannot be of type RemoteWebDriver

            } finally {
                if (screenshotFile == null) {
                    System.out.println("This WebDriver does not support screenshots");
                    return;  //get us outa here
                }
            }

            try {

                String pathString = "some path of your choice"
                File path = new File(pathString);

                if (!path.exists())
                    path.mkdirs();

                stringPath.concat("/someFileName.png");

                File newFileLocation = new File(pathString);
                System.out.println("Full path to screenshot: " + newFileLocation.getAbsolutePath());

                FileUtils.copyFile(screenshotFile, newFileLocation);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: i am using SELENIUM 3  and browser is firefox. do you have any  code snippet specific to firefox that will be help. Thanks

Comment: I have tried above code it's taking screen shot as per view ,  not capturing full content which i was able to achieve using selenium ide for firefox, so issue i am facing when i am trying to achieve same with webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old problem with Selenium browser drivers.

Try this utility: aShot

You can find it at https://github.com/yandex-qatools/ashot